# Is my understanding of cardinality of sets of strings correct?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, logic

Is my understanding of cardinality of sets of strings correct?

1) A finite set of symbols (containing $x$ symbols) and strings of finite length $n$ gives us $x^n$ finitely many strings.

2) A finite set of symbols (containing $x$ symbols) and strings of countably infinite length $\aleph_0$ gives us $x^{\aleph_0}$ uncountably many strings.

3) A countably infinite set of symbols (containing $\aleph_0$ symbols) and strings of finite length $n$ gives us $\aleph_0^n$ countably infinitely many strings.

4) A countably infinite set of symbols (containing $\aleph_0$ symbols) and strings of countably infinite length $\aleph_0$ gives us ${\aleph_0}^{\aleph_0}$ uncountably many strings.

And I've learned that there are countably infinite number of strings of finite lengths given a set of finitely many symbols, which is different from saying $x^n$, since it's talking about all values of the finite number $n$. Is there a formula to capture this notion in relation to $x^n$?

Comment: 2 is wrong unless 1 < x.  Simplify the cardinality given in 3.

Comment: The correct notation for the cardinality of countably infinite sets is $\aleph_0$; I replaced your $\aleph$ accordingly.

Comment: Thank you both. Could you answer the question at the bottom when you get a chance?

Comment: @WilliamElliot: Why would it be wrong for $x=1$? As far as I can see, with only one symbol, there is only one string with length $\aleph_0$, and $1^{\aleph_0}=1$.

Comment: @celtschk I wrote that it would be uncountably many, so I'm assuming it's wrong when x is less than or equal to 1 since there would be 1 string?

Comment: @csp2018: Ah, I saw the formula, but didn't notice the following word. True, $1$ is certainly not uncountable many.

Comment: @celtschk.  1 is not uncountably many strings.

Comment: @WilliamElliot: See my comment directly above.

Comment: i have a question : if S = {1,2,3} and S* is the set of all strings of length n $\in N$. Then S* is countable right? (according to 1) because, we say $S* = S_1 \lor S_2 \lor ... S_n$ but each of $S_i$ is countable , $|S_i| = 3^i$ , so S* as a countable union of countable sets is countable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apart from the issue about $x$ pointed out in the comments, your assertions are correct.

For the last one, if $X$ is a finite set of cardinality $x$, let $X^n$ denote the set of words of length $n$ on the alphabet $X$ (a finite set of cardinality $x^n$, as you observed). Note that, for $n = 0$, $X^0$ is the singleton containing the empty word. 
Then the set of all finite words, usually denoted $X^*$, is the union $\bigcup_{n \geqslant 0} X^n$. As a countable union of finite sets, it is countable, and hence its cardinality is $1$ if $x = 0$ and $\aleph_0$ otherwise.